Extrinsic Curvature in a conformally-flat spacetime that is also asymptotically-flat spacetime
I would appreciate if someone can confirm or correct my understanding of extrinsic-curvature (as in the ADM 3+1 decomposition of spacetime) when dealing with a conformally-flat spacetime.
(I updated the question's title and body after comments were rightfully made)
I followed mathematical derivations in literature (such as "3+1 Formalism and Bases of Numerical Relativity" ch. 8 by Gourgoulhon (2007)) and I read the answer in this thread.
I assume that a conformally-flat spacetime is also asymptotically-flat if the factor function ($\Psi$ usually) is bound. Perhaps this is even trivial to mention, but I'll try to be precise.
Is it correct to infer that in a conformally-flat spacetime that is asymptotically-flat and stretches out to infinity - the extrinsic curvature tensor $K_{mn}$ vanishes (all of its components) at infinity?

It would seem a confusing usage of the term if "asymptotically flat" spacetime did not tend to zero curvature at infinity. There may, of course, be some additional technical conditions.

The title of the question mentions conformally-flat but the body speaks only about asymptotically flat.

Thank you for the comments, I updated the question.
